# How to define and use a python function across chunks in R Markdown?

Tags: python, r, rstudio, r-markdown

Though I feel very stupid asking this question, I have not found a way to resolve this.

I am trying to define a simple python function in a code chunk in R Markdown.

```
def show(T):
  print("shape of T:", T.shape)
  print(T)
```

Then, I am trying to use it from another pyhton chunk in the same R Markdown.

```
import numpy as np
T = np.array([[...],[...], ...])
show(T)
```

But this throws an error saying that

> NameError: name 'show' is not defined

I am using RStudio 1.2.907. Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Related [Python environment persistance across chunks #1440](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1440)

Comment: @PoGibas Thanks for the comment. Knitting the whole document seems to work. Though it is bit annoying to do that when you just want to run only a piece of code, I can live with that for now :)